# generate scep256k1 public key from private key

Tags: java, bouncycastle, bitcoin

I want to use bouncycastle to specify the 32bytes private key to generate the public key corresponding to secp256k1, but I only see that bouncycastle generates the keypair directly. I need to know the base point G of the elliptic curve. How can I modify this code to achieve it?

```
private static ECKeyPair create(KeyPair keyPair) {
        BCECPrivateKey privateKey = (BCECPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
        BCECPublicKey publicKey = (BCECPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        BigInteger privateKeyVal = privateKey.getD();

        byte[] publicKeyBytes = publicKey.getQ().getEncoded(false);
        BigInteger publicKeyVal = new BigInteger(1, Arrays.copyOfRange(publicKeyBytes, 1, publicKeyBytes.length));

        return new ECKeyPair(privateKeyVal, publicKeyVal);
    }
    public static ECKeyPair createECKeyPair() throws NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
        //Add bouncy castle as key pair gen provider
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        //Generate key pair
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDSA", "BC");
        ECGenParameterSpec ecGenParameterSpec = new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256k1");
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(ecGenParameterSpec, new SecureRandom());
        //Convert KeyPair to ECKeyPair, to store keys as BigIntegers
        return ECKeyPair.create(keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You' re probably using [web3j](https://github.com/web3j/web3j) because your `create`-method belongs to [`org.web3j.crypto.ECKeyPair`](https://github.com/web3j/web3j/blob/master/crypto/src/main/java/org/web3j/crypto/ECKeyPair.java). This class provides appropriate `create`-overloads for your purpose which expect the raw private key either as `BigInteger` or as byte array (the latter requires the [web3j utilitiy classes](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.web3j/utils/4.5.8) in addition to [web3j](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.web3j/crypto/4.5.8)):

```
import org.web3j.crypto.ECKeyPair;
import java.math.BigInteger;
...
byte[] privateKey = hexStringToByteArray("a1e3ce382dafebc4ed9a9efc7d771f669745e2a88b33f2b5eb4efa8c47721346"); // e.g. from //kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/sample/sample-ecdsa.html
ECKeyPair ec =  ECKeyPair.create(new BigInteger(1, privateKey));
//ECKeyPair ec =  ECKeyPair.create(privateKey); // needs web3j utilitiy classes
System.out.println("Raw private key: " + ec.getPrivateKey().toString(16));
System.out.println("Raw public  key: " + ec.getPublicKey().toString(16));
```

Since `ECKeyPair` is implemented for Secp256k1, no curve parameters need to be specified. Note, that web3j requires BouncyCastle under the hood (although it's not explicitly used in the code above). In the example I created the byte array from a hex string for simplicity ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java)).